# How can I reduce the space between lines in a table title

Tags: tables, line-spacing

Template I am using adds a space-line after a newline in `table`.

For the table, title is it possible to discard space after new-line, where I want to reduce spacing only in the table title.

The basic code is as follow:

```tex
\documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage{tabularx, longtable, setspace}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\title{A demonstration of the \LaTeX\ class file for Wiley NJD Journals\protect\thanks{This is an example for title footnote.}}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

\begin{table}[htp!]
    \centering
    \singlespace
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth /3 +10mm}{{L{1.3cm}  @{~} C{1.7cm} @{~} C{3.6cm}  }}
      \toprule
      Study    & Some model & Storage \newline used for \newline data transfer  \\
      \midrule
      A    & Pay-per-task  & Dummy cloud, Google Drive  \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Comparative table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

- class file could be downloaded from here (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/pb-assets/assets/10991476/AMA-stix_New-1658766862393.zip), under: `ama/WileyNJD-v2.cls`:

or from [overleaf-link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-demonstration-of-the-latex-class-file-for-wiley-njd-journals/bfwqvgnbgcjc).

output is as follow:

[image]

wanted output:

[image]

Comment: duplicate of this ? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378267/how-to-reduce-spacing-between-lines-in-latex-tables

Comment: @alper Please add a link to the exact version of the class you are using

Comment: @anis The linked question seems to be about inter cell spacing not intra cell spacing

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz link is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `setspace` and `\singlespace` (but the right command would be `\singlespacing` do nothing at all.
2. Why `tabularx` if you don't use `X` columns?
3. Why specifying the column width, when TeX can do it for you?

```
\pdfmapfile{../Lato-fonts/lato.map}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

% for the first table
\newcommand{\reduce}{\linespread{0.8}\selectfont}
% for the second table
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \linespread{0.8}\selectfont\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\title{A demonstration of the \LaTeX\ class file for Wiley NJD 
  Journals\protect\thanks{This is an example for title footnote.}}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{L{1.3cm}  @{~} C{1.7cm} @{~} C{3.6cm}}
\toprule
Study  & Some model & \reduce Storage \newline used for \newline data transfer \\
\midrule
A    & Pay-per-task  & Dummy cloud, Google Drive  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Comparative table.}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
\toprule
Study & Some model & \splitcell{Storage \\ used for \\ data transfer} \\
\midrule
A     & Pay-per-task  & Dummy cloud, Google Drive  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Comparative table.}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(The first two lines are in order to employ the Lato fonts provided by the template.)

[image]

With just two lines it seems better.

[image]

Comment: Where can I find `Lato-fonts/lato.map` file? or is it automatically handled by the compiler?

Comment: Can I also use `\splitcell{}` for the other rows? looks like it also works for them

Comment: @alper, see my answer and comments to your previous question. You can use `\splitcell` wherever you want.

Comment: For the second solution when I add `\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!20}` on top of `\begin{tabular}...` the gray color for the rows' background exceeds the left and right margin of the table , but it works for the first solution.

Comment: @alper Don't color rows, it's easier and more readable. Anyway, you have to remove `@{}` at either end, if you really want to color rows.

Comment: @egrep Thanks again, I will remove colors from now on :-)